# how to upload captured photo to phpmadmin?

Tags: android

```
protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
    Map <String,String> Params = new HashMap<String, String>();
    Params.put("Name",name);
    Params.put("Image",imageString);
    return Params;
}

public void onImageAvailable(ImageReader reader) {
    Image image = null;

    try {
        image = reader.acquireLatestImage();
        ByteBuffer buffer = image.getPlanes()[0].getBuffer();
        byte[] bytes = new byte[buffer.capacity()];
        buffer.get(bytes);
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
        saveimage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        save(bytes);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (image != null) {
            image.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: convert it to base64

Comment: i already converted it

Comment: did you add this "data:image/png;base64,"+base64 into your base64 string before uploading?

Comment: You want to upload it to phpMyAdmin? phpMyAdmin is a database explorer, not an upload service. To you want to insert it into the database? Do you have a web application backed by this database? Did you create an endpoint to upload the image to?

Comment: yes i do have web application. if you dont get my point its okay. you gave no help. thanks

Comment: Hussain. yes thank you. ill try that one

Answer (score 0):

Hi First to be clear In general the image saved byte array or base64 format, You must be clear whether the image is saved byte array or base64  in your data base.

Follow the below tutorial

https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-upload-image-to-server/